# KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

I am receiving `KeyNotFoundException` whenever I try to access the key in dictionary.

I have a `PricingRules` class which has a dictionary:

```
public class PricingRules
{
    Dictionary<ItemCode, Money> pricing_rules;

    public PricingRules()
    {
        pricing_rules = new Dictionary<ItemCode, Money>();
        pricing_rules.Add(new ItemCode("A"), new Money(50));
        pricing_rules.Add(new ItemCode("B"), new Money(30));
        pricing_rules.Add(new ItemCode("C"), new Money(20));
        pricing_rules.Add(new ItemCode("D"), new Money(15));
    }

    public void itemScanned(ItemCode itemCode, Money amount)
    {
        amount.Add(pricing_rules[itemCode]);
    }

    public Money AmountForItem(ItemCode itemCode)
    {
        return pricing_rules[itemCode];
    }
}
```

The key in the dictionary is of type `ItemCode`:

```
public class ItemCode
{
    private readonly string itemCode;

    public ItemCode(string itemCode)
    {
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return itemCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and the value is of type `Money`:

```
public class Money
{
    private int amount;

    public Money(int amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Money money = (Money)obj;
        return this.amount == money.amount;
    }

    public void Add(object obj)
    {
        Money money = (Money)obj;
        this.amount += money.amount;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return amount.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I have tried overriding the `GetHashCode()` function to return the HashCode of the primitive type in the class but it still is giving `KeyNotFoundException`

The test I have written is:

```
public class PricingRulesShould
{
    [Fact]
    void ReturnValueFiftyWhenKeyIsA()
    {
        Money expected = new Money(50);
        PricingRules pr = new PricingRules();

        ItemCode itemcode = new ItemCode("A");
        Money actual = pr.AmountForItem(itemcode);

        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to make `ItemCode` to implement `IEquatable<ItemCode>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Dictionary` accesses its elements, it looks for the equality of keys.
Since the `ItemCode` is not a primitive type, when you compare `new ItemCode("A") == new ItemCode("A")` you should get `false` as a result, because they are **different** instances with identical contents.
What you can do is to implement [`IEquatable<ItemCode>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netcore-3.1) by the `ItemCode` class:

```
public class ItemCode : IEquatable<ItemCode>
{
    private readonly string itemCode;

    public ItemCode(string itemCode)
    {
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return itemCode != null ? itemCode.GetHashCode() : 0;
    }

    public bool Equals(ItemCode other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(itemCode, other.itemCode);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return obj is ItemCode ic && Equals(ic);
    }
}
```